# How to change the way Oracle XE Application Express displays the NULL value?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm using Oracle 10g XE edition via Application Express and NULLs are displayed using `-` character. I found from the parameter listing that:

```
+-------+-------+------------+--------------------------------------------+
| Name  | Value | Is Default |                Description                 |
+-------+-------+------------+--------------------------------------------+
| event | -     | TRUE       | debug event control - default null string  |
+-------+-------+------------+--------------------------------------------+
```

Is there a way to change this value so that NULLs are displayed `NULL` instead of `-`?

Comment: what is the column type of value?

Comment: What application are you using to display the data?  Oracle the database has no influence on how a particular front-end application displays a `NULL`.  Different front-end applications have different ways to customize the display of the data.

Comment: The data type is int. I'm using Oracle XE Application Express.

Comment: "Oracle" doesn't display any values. Your SQL client does. Look at the configuration options of your SQL tool.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question, my SQL Client is Oracle XE Application Express (default client which comes from the installation). The parameter is show in the question, and I'm asking how to change it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the default behaviour of reports created in Oracle Application Express (Apex).

You can change it to `NULL` or blank it out entirely by editing the Report Attributes - **Show Null Values As**.